# PHP-FPM very slow

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

i have a little problem with nginx and php7.0-fpm. I have much less requests per second than apache + mod_php.

For example (same server)

[image: ab tests]

Requested script in tests is simple echo.

//EDIT:

nginx conf & www.conf & php.ini
http://pastebin.com/9m6yx8h4

//EDIT2:

if is use apache with fast=cgi module instead mod_php module i will get same result than nginx + fast-cgi (30r./s.). Is problem in php-fpm?

Where could be the problem?

Comment: The problem is with your Nginx configuration. Since you've given us no information we can't be more specific. It's likely to do with caching. If you'd like more specific help I suggest you edit your question to include Nginx and Apache configuration, some logs if applicable, some information on your testing, that sort of thing.

Comment: Please copy the test results as text to the question. Please also include the configuration files directly into the text instead of using external services.

Comment: Your link to nginx/apache conf only gives apache conf

Answer (score 2):

Your tests are not on similarly configured servers.

Your Apache server served all its requests with keepalives enabled, but your nginx server served all its requests with keepalives disabled, which creates a significant reduction in performance as a new TCP connection must be opened for every request.

By default, nginx has keepalives enabled, so you must have explicitly disabled them somehow. Inspect your nginx configuration carefully and remove any directives related to `keepalive`, so that nginx uses its default behavior. Then try your benchmark again.

Comment: i have activated keepalive, can i contact you? i am really frustated

Comment: @Carma You also need to configure keepalive for nginx--php-fpm, [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9481657/1068283).

Comment: doesnt work, no effect :(